# How to set a filesystem size limit for DB2 database? Is it possible?

Tags: db2, datafile, db2-luw

I'm looking for a way to limit a DB2 database size (in disk)  at creation time. But I couldn't find it.

At SQL server we can do by this way:

```
Create Database MyDatabase
on (Name='MyDatabase_Data',
    Filename='c:\db\BdUnisanta_Data.mdf',
    Size= 20MB,
    FileGrowth = 10%,
    Maxsize=100MB)
log on 
    (Name = 'MyDatabase_log',
     Filename = 'c:\db\MyDatabase_Log.ldf',
     Size = 5MB,
     FileGrowth = 5%,
     MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED
     )
```

What would be the equivalent form in DB2? Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Tablespaces in DB2 have a `MAXSIZE` attribute that you can use.  You can specify these size attributes in the `CREATE DATABASE` statement (or when creating additional tablespaces), or use `ALTER TABLESPACE` to set them later.

```
create database mydb
   automatic storage yes
   on C:\mydb
   user tablespace managed by automatic storage
      initialsize 20 M increasesize 10 percent maxsize 100 M
```

You could specify similar options for the system catalog tablespace and the default system temporary tablespace, but I would not recommend doing so.

Comment: It was a very clear answer!